Variable gets reset in React
When I login,  App.js works and give me the correct habit, but when anything gets changed in the Firebase Realtime Database, it just sets the path to whatever is default in index.js. Once reloaded everythings works until something in the database changes.
App.js:
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { db } from './firebase';
import { set, ref, onValue } from "firebase/database"
import Habit from './Habit.jsx'
import './App.css'
import { readFromDatabase } from "react-router-dom"

function App({ email }) {
  const [habits, setHabits] = useState([]);
  const [habitName, setHabitName] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const encodedEmail = email.replace(/@/g, '_at_').replace(/\./g, '_dot_');
  console.log(encodedEmail)

  const readFromDatabase = useCallback(() => {
    if (!isLoading) {
      setIsLoading(true);
      let dbRef = ref(db, `/${encodedEmail}`);
      console.log("first runs", encodedEmail)
      onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        console.log('Data:', data);
        console.log(`Reading from path: /${encodedEmail}`);
        console.log(email, "email")
        if (data !== null) {
          const newHabits = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({
            name: key,
            ...data[key]
          }));
          setHabits(newHabits);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
    }
  }, [encodedEmail, email, isLoading]);

  useEffect(() => {
    readFromDatabase();
  }, [readFromDatabase]);



  const writeToDatabase = () => {
    const cDate = new Date().toDateString()
    set(ref(db, `/${encodedEmail}/${habitName}`), {
      Name: habitName,
      Creation: cDate,
      Last: cDate,
      Repeated: 0
    });
    setHabitName(' ')
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {habits.map((habit) => {
          return (
            <Habit habit={habit} key={habit.Name} encodedEmail={encodedEmail} />
          )
        })}
      </div>

      <input type="text" value={habitName} onChange={(e) => setHabitName(e.target.value)} required />
      <button onClick={(e) => writeToDatabase()} className="createButton">Create</button>

    </div>
  );
}


export default App;

login.jsx:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './login.css'
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from './firebase';

const Login = ({ onLogin }) => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const login = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, username, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                console.log(userCredential);
                onLogin(username)
            })
    };
    const signup = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, username, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                console.log(userCredential);
                onLogin(username)
            })
    };
    const [isSignUp, setIsSignUp] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (isSignUp) {
            signup(e);
        } else {
            login(e);
        }
        console.log(username)
    };

    return (
        <div className='loginContainer'>
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header">
                    <h2>Account</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} required />

                        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type='password' id="password" name='password' value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} required />
                        <div className="card-footer">
                            <button type="submit" className="form-button" onClick={(e) => setIsSignUp(false)}>Login</button>
                            <button type="submit" className='form-button' onClick={(e) => { setIsSignUp(true); handleSubmit(e); }}>Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div className='change-type'>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;

index.js:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Login from './login';
import './firebase'

function Parent() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  return (
    <Main onLogin={setEmail}>
      <App email={email} />
    </Main>
  );
}

function Main({ onLogin, children }) {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  const handleLogin = (mail) => {
    console.log('Logging in with email:', mail); // Debug: Check when this function is called
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
    onLogin(mail);
  };

  return (
    isLoggedIn ? children : <Login onLogin={handleLogin} />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));

Habit.jsx:
import React from "react";
import { set, ref } from "firebase/database"
import { db } from './firebase';

const Habit = ({ habit, encodedEmail }) => {
    const date = new Date().toDateString();
    const lastDate = new Date(habit.Last);
    /*const creationDate = new Date(habit.Creation);
    const differenceInDates = Math.floor(Math.max(new Date(habit.Last) - new Date(habit.Creation), 0) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); */
    const lastIsToday = (lastDate - new Date(date)) >= 0;
    /*console.log(lastIsToday, lastDate - new Date(date))*/

    const updateHabit = () => {
        if (lastIsToday === false & habit.Name) {
            set(ref(db, `/${encodedEmail}/${habit.Name}`), {
                Name: habit.Name,
                Creation: habit.Creation,
                Last: date,
                Repeated: habit.Repeated + 1
            });
        }
    }
    const history = () => {
        return (
            Array.from({ length: habit.Repeated }).map((_, index) => (
                <div key={habit.Name} className="square"></div>
            ))
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="habit">
            <div className="main">
                <div className="name">
                    <strong>
                        {habit.Name}
                    </strong>
                </div>
                <div className="square" onClick={updateHabit} style={lastIsToday ? { backgroundColor: "green" } : { backgroundColor: "red" }}>
                </div>
                <div className="habitHistory">
                    {history()}
                </div>

            </div>
            <hr />
        </div >
    )
}

export default Habit;

Console:
jarmaralukas123_at_gmail_dot_com
App.js:20 first runs jarmaralukas123_at_gmail_dot_com
App.js:23 Data: {" Meditate": {…}, " Workout": {…}}
App.js:24 Reading from path: /jarmaralukas123_at_gmail_dot_com
App.js:25 jarmaralukas123@gmail.com email
App.js:14 jarmaralukas123_at_gmail_dot_com
4App.js:14 jarmaralukas123_at_gmail_dot_com
App.js:23 Data: {" Meditate": {…}, " Workout": {…}, test: {…}}
App.js:24 Reading from path: /jarmaralukas123_at_gmail_dot_com
App.js:25 jarmaralukas123@gmail.com email
App.js:23 Data: {jarmaralukas123_at_gmail_dot_com: {…}, lukas_dot_jarmara_at_gmail_dot_com: {…}}
App.js:24 Reading from path: /
App.js:25  email
App.js:14 jarmaralukas123_at_gmail_dot_com

I was expecting for it to read from the encoded email path, not from whatever is set here in the useState in index.js.

You should define the function you call in the useEffect inside the useEffect too

Solved using Jack McBride's tip plus added       if (encodedEmail !== "") {} check
